# Creating a windows 8 app package from VS fails

Tags: windows-8

I have just finished my first Windows 8 app and I wanted to build the packages to upload them to the store.

In VS 2012 you can find this under Project -> Store -> Create App packages...

The problem is, after creating all the packages, the certification tool runs and it fails.

The only fail point is "Performance suspend". It says that my app it is not suspending correctly and this is a problem.

I have run the Certification tool on my dev PC x64, and the result is "Passed" for everything.

I think this has something to do with the ARM package. While testing on a Surface tablet I saw that the app is not suspending when I go to the start screen.

I know the suspension works correct on x86, x64 and I even tested it on ARM (closing the app).

Do you have any ideas why there are problems with the suspension when the app is not focused on an ARM device? Has anybody encountered this issue before?

Comment: is this HTML5/JS or C#/VB? What code executes when your app is suspending - are you serializing state? calling a service?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add this details.
The app is written in C# and in the suspension event I am serializing 3 objects and saving them in local folder.
The code works OK when I close the app (drag from top to bottom), but the event it is not fired when I switch away from the app.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it looks like this is a performance issue that is only showing up on ARM (if you are getting "Passed" on the WACK on your dev PC x64 machine).  There is a performance requirement when submitting apps to the Windows Store; check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/14/common-windows-store-certification-errors-3-8-app-must-meet-the-basic-performance-criteria-on-a-low-power-computer.aspx) for details.

I think you have 2 options: 
1. Submit your app to the Windows Store only for x86 and x64 processors (not ARM).
2.  Optimize the code in your suspend event to make it run faster, so it will meet the requirements on ARM.  Here is an article on [how to minimize your suspend time in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994640.aspx).

One more thing: to test suspend, I found that I need to not only switch away from my currently-running app, but also go to a new Windows Store app to force the first one into Suspend mode (just going to the desktop, for example, doesn't always do it).  To see if your app has really been suspended or not, you can open the Task Manager.  In the Menu bar under "View", select "Status values" and then "Show suspended status".  Then you should be able to see which apps are suspended in the Task Manager.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jennifer, and sorry for responding so late. I have already submitted the app to Microsoft (actually before asking the question), and for the moment it seems that it passed the WACK (the app is at the manual test phase).
Anyway, I have changed the suspension actions (from 3 file writes to just local settings saves) and I think this will help. I haven't run the WACK from VS again, but when I do that, I will let you know if I have any more problems.

Comment: Thank you again for the help. I just received an email that my app was approved :D